# Use Redis with AWS SAM (Redis Client Error)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis

Right now what I'm trying to do is that every time a request is made, a query is made to the **Redis** service. The problem is that when using a basic configuration, it would not be working. The error is the following:

> INFO  Redis Client Error Error: connec    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node} port: 6379127.0.0.1',

I have as always running **redis-server** with its corresponding credentials listening to port **127.0.0.1:6379**. I know that **AWS SAM** runs with a container, and the issue is probably due to a **network configuration**, but the only command that **AWS SAM CLI** provides me is **--host**. How could i fix this?

my code is the following, although it is not very relevant:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import processData from './src/lambda-data-dictionary-read/core/service/controllers/processData';

export async function lambdaHandler(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    const body: any = await processData(event.queryStringParameters);

    const url = process.env.REDIS_URL || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
    const client = createClient({
        url,
    });

    client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

    await client.connect();

    await client.set('key', 'value');
    const value = await client.get('key');

    console.log('----', value, '----');

    const response: APIGatewayProxyResult = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body,
    };

    if (body.error) {
        return {
            statusCode: 404,
            body,
        };
    }

    return response;
}
```

My template.yaml:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    lambda-data-dictionary-read

    Sample SAM Template for lambda-data-dictionary-read

Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 0

Resources:
    IndexFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: app/
            Handler: index.lambdaHandler
            Runtime: nodejs16.x
            Timeout: 10
            Architectures:
                - x86_64
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    ENV: !Ref develope
                    REDIS_URL: !Ref redis://127.0.0.1:6379
            Events:
                Index:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /api/lambda-data-dictionary-read
                        Method: get
        Metadata:
            BuildMethod: esbuild
            BuildProperties:
                Minify: true
                Target: 'es2020'
                Sourcemap: true
                UseNpmCi: true
```

Im using:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "sam build --cached --beta-features && sam local start-api --port 8080 --host 127.0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right: 'port: 6379127.0.0.1' why does the port have an IP address concated to the number?

Comment: Yes, it is true that it looks strange @Stefano. Redis on local is pointing to 127.0.0.1:6379 and in my template.yaml I have not specified anything

Comment: you're not passing a config object into the createClient function, how does it know what to connect to? what happens if you explicitly set the the address? createClient({url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'})

Comment: I just tried that but the same thing keeps happening. I updated the code listed here

Comment: are you able to connect to the redis db from a shell?

Comment: Yes, it is currently running in a terminal

Comment: AWS lambdas are serverless, they are not running on the same system you are running redis.

Comment: Ok, I understand. How can I tell the AWS SAM docker image that I want to connect to my local redis? using docker-compose, for example?